# Passing function identifiers to change what function is used for a given subroutine FORTRAN

Tags: function, fortran

In a language like python, I can pass functions like an object as an argument for other functions. Is there an equivalent syntax in fortran?

Python example:

```py
def first_func():
    print('hello world')

def second_func():
    print('HELLO WORLD')

def third_func(f):
    f()

third_func(first_func)
third_func(second_func)
```

So it would print out:

```
$> hello world
$> HELLO WORLD
```

I understand that in fortran I could pass a reference number to the subroutine, ie 1 results in one function and 2 results in another. However, what I am asking is if there is a way to pass the identifier for the function (ie if I wrote `real function f(x)`, is there a way I could pass `f` to the subroutine as an argument, while at a different time, pass a different function `real function g(x)` as an argument?

Like so:

```
subroutine loop_funcs(func, max_iter)
    real, intent(in) :: function func
    integer, intent(in) :: max_iter
    do i = 1, max_iter
        func(i)
    end do
end subroutine loop_funcs
```

Comment: Have you tried `real, intent(in) :: func`? Note, however, that `func(i)` cannot appear by itself. You're saying it's a real function so you must use it in an expression.

Comment: The linked question is about subroutines but it is really the same, with the only difference having to declare the return type for the external ones - which you should avoid.